# Two exact copies of folder using FTP and command-line only

Tags: backup, ftp

I'm looking for any solution that will allow me to emulate functionallity similar to Dropbox/rsync using only FTP protocol and command-line.

The general problem is, that I have to run it on a very limited Linux (actually NAS), so I can't install / use to complex solutions (not enough resources to run) and/or GUI utils, as I have no GUI there. SSH also works weak on that NAS and is not present at all on one of destinations.

What I need, is to have a command-line (bash) script or program that I will be able to run periodically (via CRON) that will assure that `source` and `destination` are identical:

- all files on both sides copied to both sides,
- if two files of the same name exists, copy newest version of a file to both sides,
- delete on one side all files that are missing on another one.

Of course, this solution must support iteration on all subfolders of both source and destination, for this to work succesfully -- there will be a large directory structure on both sides.

I've tried many backups solutions, but most of them failed for one of these reasons:

- unable to create exact duplicate copy of both sides and offering incremental backup instead,
- not able to be run directly from command-line, on very limited Linux distro.

I was advised to use Unison and give it a good try. This really looks good, but it uses SSH, and I'm unable to establish SSH connection to one of my destinations (not supported) -- i.e. FTP access is the only available way.

The perfect solution for me would be anything that I can run (command-line or  configuration) like this:

```
something.sh path/to/local/folder ftp://user:pass@111.11.11.1/path/to/folder
```

If it does exists at all...

Comment: Could you clarify what you have on the NAS side (FTP server, client or both) and what you have on the other side? Do you need to be able to synchronize between two limited machines, or can you arrange to always transfer between a limited-machine and a less-limited machine?

Comment: @Gilles: First option: I have a limited NAS (has rsync and ftp but lacks many system-level commands, clients, services and programs) and even more limited video-player that actually gives out nothing else except FTP (and Samba). To make things even more complex, both devices are not in the same network and are accessible only via external IP (NAS has it own, player is behind NAT and uses DynDNS to workaround dynamic IP address problem).

Answer (score 2):

One general thing: as far as I know, ftp cannot be used to set the remote time stamp, because this is not supported by the protocol. However, this is OK in your case, since you only want to make sure that data that is newer than that on the server is transferred, and the rest left.

I think that you can use `rsync` with ftp using fuse and curlftpfs. First, mount the ftp filesystem locally:

```
curlftpfs -o user=username:password ftp://whatever.ftp/ mountpoint/
```

Then, use `rsync` the usual way for local mirrors:

```
rsync -azv source mountpoint/whatever/dir/
```

rsync is a powerful tool with many options to fine tune the synchronization of folders and files.

Another option: `wput`; this (written I think as a counterpart to wget) [can compare](http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html) remote and local time stamps using the **-N** option. Furthermore, wput recursively transfers the directories, so I think that this is actually the solution that you are looking for. Example:

```
wput somedir ftp://user:pass@some.server/remote/dir/
```

Will create a mirror of "somedir/" on the remote server. If you re-run the command without modifying the local somedir, no further files will be transferred.

Comment: Hm... I'm a Linux newbie, but I have to revalidate my knowledge. All my sources about `rsync` that I have read always claimed: *You want to use rsync over FTP? You need to find another way to do this. rsync **does not work** that way!* Look [here](http://serverfault.com/a/24627/127070) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/34895) for example.

Comment: You are right, silly me. I revised the answer.

Comment: This does sound interesting, unfortunatelly, there is no `curlftpfs ` on my NAS and no way to install it. I asked for FTP, because this is all I have there. I'll give a try to `wput`, but after first look it looks only like a file-transfering tool, so I would have to do all the magic (that `rsync` does) of finding and sending only modified files myself. I'm pretty sure that it is more than I can handle due to my limited knowledge of Linux/bash.

Comment: Well, the `-N` option of wput takes care of some of your problem.

Comment: P.S. and wput is recursive, so no need to find the files yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`lftp` has a `mirror` command (and `mirror -R` for reverse mirror).

Comment: This does sound interesting, unfortunatelly, there is no `lftp` on my NAS and no way to install it. I asked for FTP, because this is all I have there. If installing addtional software would be an option, I would problably solve this problem myself, without asking.

Comment: lftp is a FTP client. It would talk to the FTP server on the NAS. Do you mean you need to synchronise two NASes directly between each other.

Comment: @trejder If installing additional software isn't an option, why did you "try many backup solutions"? You already knew you couldn't install them! Please state your problem accurately.

Comment: @sch: Exactly as in my answer to Gilles comment above: Two devices in two different networks, one is NAS, second is video-player with some unknown distro on-board, able to be access only via FTP (and Samba).

Comment: @angus: Maybe "many" is to strong word. I've tried rsync+mounting external system (faild) and unison (also failed). Installing additional software is an option, but only if that software is available as IPKG package, because using Optware/IPKG is the only way to install something to that NAS. And AFAIK there is not IPKG package for `lftp`.